# use of Row_Number() in a view occasionally skips a number

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, row-number

I'm calling an SQL view from crystal report. The view retrieves a few fields, and one of them is:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY visitNum ORDER BY visitNumId) AS RowNumber
```

Most of the times, the field RowNumber shows the number of rows in the order requested, but occasionally it skips a number.
I’d see:

```
RowNumber | Value | Description
------------------|---------------  
1         |   23  |   DFS  
2         |   11  |   UJG  
4         |   15  |   EFD
```

The RowNumber field skipped number 3 and went directly to 4. 
The actual number of rows is 3. 
I’d expect to see the following return:

```
RowNumber | Value | Description  
------------------|--------------------  
1        |   23   |    DFS  
2        |   11   |    UJG  
3        |   15   |    EFD
```

Does anyone know the reason for this?

The whole view is:   SELECT  TOP (100) PERCENT VIEW_Visit_SubjectsDetails_Takshetem_NotParsed.visitNum,  VIEW_Visit_SubjectsDetails_Takshetem_NotParsed.TotalPrice, 
CASE WHEN (View_ParamDesc.Param IS NULL) THEN '' ELSE dbo.View_ParamDesc.Param END AS Param, VIEW_Visit_SubjectsDetails_Takshetem_NotParsed.visitNumId,                          VIEW_Visit_SubjectsDetails_Takshetem_NotParsed.remarks, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VIEW_Visit_SubjectsDetails_Takshetem_NotParsed.visitNum
ORDER BY VIEW_Visit_SubjectsDetails_Takshetem_NotParsed.visitNumId) AS RowNumber
FROM   VIEW_Visit_SubjectsDetails_Takshetem_NotParsed LEFT OUTER JOIN View_ParamDesc ON VIEW_Visit_SubjectsDetails_Takshetem_NotParsed.visitNum = View_ParamDesc.agentNum AND                          VIEW_Visit_SubjectsDetails_Takshetem_NotParsed.visitNumId = View_ParamDesc.visitNumId where  visitNum = '117'

Comment: Can you show the whole view?

Comment: I am guessing you have NOLOCK in your views?

Comment: Or maybe there's an inner query that numbers the rows and outer where clause that leaves out rows?

Comment: I added the whole view

Comment: Any chance you can include the source data too. Also do you normally use table aliases to simplify your SQL?

Comment: @SimonDarlow this is the definition of the view. When I call it I just add the where part of it.